# Multiple Material Tables in one component Angular 12

Tags: angular, angular-material

I'm using Material table with pagination and sortable modules.
I know that a lot of subjects are talking about multiple tables in one component.
But the problem is that i'm in a case where it does not work and i don't understand why..

Paginator is working properly with my 2 tables.
But MatSort is just not working.. I put my mouse in the cell, it shows that i can click to sort, but there is no changes on the data..

```
  displayedColumnsOne: string[] = ['group', 'action'];
  @ViewChild('tableOnePaginator', { static: false }) tableOnePaginator!: MatPaginator;
  @ViewChild('tableOneSort', { static: false }) tableOneSort!: MatSort;
  dataSource = new MatTableDataSource<any>();

....
  updateDataTable(): void {
    this.changeDetectorRefs.detectChanges();
    this.dataSource.paginator = this.tableOnePaginator;
    this.dataSource.sort = this.tableOneSort;
  }
```

```
<mat-table #tableOneSort="matSort" matTableExporter [dataSource]="dataSource" matSort matSortActive="group" matSortDirection="desc" matSortDisableClear class="mat-elevation-z8 col-md-12 col-xl-6 offset-xl-3" #exporter="matTableExporter">
...
<ng-container matColumnDef="group">
 <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header>Groupe</mat-header-cell>
 <mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element}} </mat-cell>
</ng-container>
...
<mat-paginator #tableOnePaginator="matPaginator" [pageSizeOptions]="[10, 15, 20]" showFirstLastButtons aria-label="Nombre d'élements par page"></mat-paginator>
```

user.module

```
    MatTableExporterModule,
    MatTableModule,
    MatPaginatorModule,
    MatSortModule,
```

app.module

```
    MatTableModule,
    MatTableExporterModule,
    MatPaginatorModule,
    MatSortModule,
```